# G is a set of all non zero real numbers with binary relation * is defined on G as

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For every $a, b$ belongs to $G$
   $a*b=ab/2$
I have to find out whether $(G, *)$ is an abelian group or not
I have gone up to identity but stuck at inverse please someone help

Comment: The identity element is $2$ and the inverse of an element is $\frac{4}{a}$

Comment: How it is 4/a can u explain it

Comment: Yeipi  Please do not answer in comments.  Also, the inverse of an element is dependent on the element.  Not every element a, b, c, d, ... $\in G$ has the inverse $\frac 4a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse of an element $a\in G$ is $\frac{4}{a}$, which is to say $a^{-1}=\frac{4}{a}$. The reason why is because $a*b=2\Leftrightarrow \frac{ab}{2}=2\Leftrightarrow b=\frac{4}{a}$. The clue is to look that the identity element is $2$ and just find which circumstances imply $ab=2$.